# Replacing Items in an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

I have a function which is supposed to replace all instances of variables (represented as `NSStrings`) from an `NSDictionary` with their corresponding values before calling another procedure. I ended up doing this with a simple `for` loop, though I suspect that there is a better way.  Do you have a suggestion how to do this differently?

```
+ (double)runProgram:(id)program usingVariables:(NSDictionary *)variables {        
    NSMutableArray *stack;
    if ([program isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        stack = [program mutableCopy];
        for (int i=0; i<stack.count; i++) {
            /* replace variable values with NSNumber values */
            NSNumber *variableValue = [variables valueForKey:[stack objectAtIndex:i]];
            if ([variableValue isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
                [stack replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:variableValue];
            }
            /* all variables should be replaced now */
        }
    }
    return [self popOperandOffProgramStack:stack];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
+ (double)runProgram:(id)program usingVariables:(NSDictionary *)variables {        
    NSMutableArray *stack;
    if ([program isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
```

Checking the type of incoming parameters is a little suspicious. Do you really want to allow other parameters and just ignore them?

```
        stack = [program mutableCopy];
```

This process would actually be easier if you didn't create a copy, but instead create an empty NSMutableArray and add the filtered objects to it.

```
        for (int i=0; i<stack.count; i++) {
```

Presumably, you are using this because you need the indexes to replace the objects. If you stop making a copy, you should be able to replace this a foreach loop over the program.

```
            /* replace variable values with NSNumber values */
            NSNumber *variableValue = [variables valueForKey:[stack objectAtIndex:i]];
            if ([variableValue isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
```

Again why are you checking types? Are there other things besides numbers in your variables? If there are, do you just want to ignore them?

```
                [stack replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:variableValue];
            }
            /* all variables should be replaced now */
```

This comment isn't true here, because its on the wrong side of the brace

```
        }
    }
    return [self popOperandOffProgramStack:stack];
}
```

Comment: Also, if 'program' is not an NSArray then 'stack' is uninitialized in the return statement.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  I agree on most points.  In the case of the `NSNumber *variableValue` test, I imagine that there will be some objects which will not be found in the `variables` `NSDictionary`.  Rather than testing if there is nothing in the dictionary for that key, I opted to test that the object returned was in fact a kind of `NSNumber` before doing anything.  I don't want to replace anything if there is nothing in `variables` for that key.

Comment: Do you think it's better to explicitly test for null instead?

Comment: The technique of testing classes and ignoring input if it is not what you expect is something I learned from watching the iPhone dev videos from Stanford (http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal), although I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly... The `runProgram:usingVariables` is API so I can't be certain that the input is as I would expect. How would you handle erroneous values?

Comment: By the way, I really liked your suggestion to create an empty `NSMutableArray` and add each step (replacing variables on the way) rather than replacing variables later.  It's much easier to read - thank you!

Comment: @jaresty, I think it is better to explicitly check for null. If you check for null, I can tell that you are checking whether the element was actually in the dictionary. It's not obvious from your code above that that is what you checking for.

Comment: @jaresty, there are different theories on how to handle invalid data. I don't like simply ignoring input because it makes so that when the invalid input happens, things just don't work without any explanation. Depending on the situation, I might not have a check, and trust that I'll get a selector not implemented error which make the problem obvious. Or I might put in an assertion, so that I only check the type during debugging. At the very least, I'd log the fact that invalid data is found.

Comment: @WinstonEwert thanks - I agree.  I added an explicit check for nil and NSLog if the value isn't as expected.  Please let me know if you have any further suggestions!

Comment: @jaresty, you are stilling ignoring in the case that program isn't an NSArray. (and I still think you simply shouldn't be checking the types. But you can ignore if you choose)

Comment: Ok - I added an explicit else to catch non-NSArray program values.  I'm still conflicted about the type-checking since I've heard a different argument from the Stanford lecture I'm listening to.  I can see advantages and disadvantages to each, but as I'm working through that class right now I think I'll stick to this methodology for now.

Comment: @jaresty, fair enough. There are reasonable arguments on either side of the question of doing those type checks. Obviously, I come down on the one side, but I don't think its the only reasonable way.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to handle this answer in two parts, as they're two distinct issues I want to address here:

```
+ (double)runProgram:(id)program usingVariables:(NSDictionary *)variables {        
    NSMutableArray *stack;
    if ([program isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        stack = [program mutableCopy];
        for (int i=0; i<stack.count; i++) {
            /* replace variable values with NSNumber values */
            NSNumber *variableValue = [variables valueForKey:[stack objectAtIndex:i]];
            if ([variableValue isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
                [stack replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:variableValue];
            }
            /* all variables should be replaced now */
        }
    }
    return [self popOperandOffProgramStack:stack];
}
```

First, let's change the method signature to something that makes a whole lot more sense:

```
+ (double)runProgram:(NSArray *)program usingVariables:(NSDictionary *)variables;
```

The method only makes sense if `program` is an array.  If it's not an array, then what does the method body actually look like?  It looks like this:

```
return [self popOperandOffProgramStack:nil];
```

So let's change the argument to `NSArray *` rather than `id`.  Now our method is more explicitly clear to callers that we except an `NSArray`, and if you don't have an array to send, send `nil`, because that's how we're going to use any non-array argument anyway.

Now that we've change the argument, we can get rid of the type check in the body.

---

Now to the second point I want to address in the body.  First, in Objective-C, `forin` loops are faster then the other available loops, so use them where you can.

I think the method body works much better as such:

```
+ (double)runProgram:(NSArray *)program usingVariables:(NSDictionary *)variables { 
    NSMutableArray *stack = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (id obj in program) {
        if ([variables[obj] isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
            [stack addObject:variables[obj]];
        } else {
            [stack addObject:obj];
        }
    }
    return [self popOperandOffProgramStack:stack];
}
```

As a note, the `else` block is in there simply in order to rewrite your existing code and produce identical results.  If objects that are not `NSNumbers` should be added to the array, simply remove the `else` block.